# Firebase: node-tar or npm that is incompatible with this version of Node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, npm, firebase-cli

I have an Angular Project and I am trying to use `firebase deploy` after building the project. After "hosting: preparing dist directory for upload" it fails with the following error.

> WARNING: You are likely using a version of node-tar or npm that is
>   incompatible with this version of Node.js. Please use either the
>   version of npm that is bundled with Node.js, or a version of npm (>
>   5.5.1 or < 5.4.0) or node-tar (> 4.0.1) that is compatible with Node.js 9 and above. node[38453]: ../src/node_zlib.cc:437:static void
>   node::(anonymous namespace)::ZCtx::Init(const
>   FunctionCallbackInfo &): Assertion `args.Length() == 7 &&
>   "init(windowBits, level, memLevel, strategy, writeResult,
>   writeCallback," " dictionary)"' failed.  1: node::Abort()
>   [/usr/local/bin/node]  2: node::Assert(char const* const (*) [4])
>   [/usr/local/bin/node]  3: node::(anonymous
>   namespace)::ZCtx::Init(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo const&)
>   [/usr/local/bin/node]  4:
>   v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void
>   (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo const&)) [/usr/local/bin/node]
>   5: v8::internal::MaybeHandle
>   v8::internal::(anonymous
>   namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper(v8::internal::Isolate*,
>   v8::internal::Handle,
>   v8::internal::Handle,
>   v8::internal::Handle,
>   v8::internal::Handle,
>   v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/usr/local/bin/node]  6:
>   v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments,
>   v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]  7: 0x3e504a2842fd Abort
>   trap: 6

I checked my version of node (v.9.6.1) and npm (5.6.0). I have tried removing node and npm and reinstalling them, without luck. I have not been able to find the node-tar version.

If anyone could help point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Comment: This is a warning, not an error. You can likely move on without issue.

Comment: @R.Richards I have been trying to deploy for ages (several hours) and keep getting this message. There is still no deployment in the deployment history on firebase.

Comment: If you run `npm ls node-tar`, do you then see the version you have installed?

Comment: This is a long shot, but... do you have more than one copy of node/npm installed? I see the current `firebase-tools` on github has `"bin": { "firebase": "./bin/firebase" }` in package.json, and `./bin/firebase` has the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env node`, so it should be running whichever version of node is called `node` in the `PATH`, and `node --version` should refer to the same version. At least if you're on Linux. And if it's not different on your version of firebase, which seems unlikely. And if you're on a different shell than `/usr/bin/env` with a different `PATH` that could also explain it.

Comment: @R.Richards `npm ls node-tar` does not show any version installed for my current project. I have tried to do a `npm install node-tar` but it states `Not Found: node-tar@latest`

Comment: Try installing it this way: `npm install tar` [node-tar npm site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar).

Comment: @R.Richards Tar is installed and ran the `npm install tar` script. Same error.

Ran `npm ls tar`. Shows two versions tar@2.2.1 as a dependancy for angular/firebase and tar@4.4.0 as the one I installed just then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey man I just had the issue. After upgrading node and npm to the latest version I figured it was coming from the firebase cli.

I just `npm install -g firebase-tools` and then `firebase deploy` was working again !